# Filter by field, and if zero results then filter by other field

Tags: sql-server, where

How should a `WHERE` clause be constructed, such that:

- It filters by a certain field
- If there are zero results for filtering by the aforementioned field, then it filters by another field?

For example, if we have this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(
  [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
  [FirstDate] DATETIME,
  [SecondDate] DATETIME
);
```

... with these records:

```
INSERT INTO Items ([Id], [FirstDate], [SecondDate])
VALUES 
(1, '2021-1-1', '2022-1-1'),
(2, '2022-1-1', '2023-1-1'), 
(3, '2022-1-1', '2024-1-1'), 
(4, '2024-1-1', '2025-1-1'),
(5, '2024-1-1', '2026-6-1')
```

... then I want to filter by `FirstDate` and `SecondDate`, such that:

- If we specify `FirstDate` and `SecondDate` to filter for `2022-1-1`, records 2 & 3 will be returned (**but not 1!**).
- If we specify `FirstDate` and `SecondDate` to filter for `2024-1-1`, records 4 & 5 will be returned (**but not 3!**).
- If we specify `FirstDate` and `SecondDate` to filter for `2025-1-1`, record 4 will be returned.

Comment: Let's restate your issue to see if that might lead to better understanding. Your two date (not datetime) columns represent a period (date range - starts on FirstDate and ends on SecondDate). So give a date of interest (x), you want those rows where x is >= FirstDate and x < SecondDate. Is this correct?

Comment: @SMor, completely no :) The two dates represent "singular" dates, not a range. More so, I just used dates as an example; the type could be any other type.

Comment: It seems a simple OR in the where clause would do what you want - e.g., where (d1 = x) or {d2 = x) but your goal is not clear.

Comment: To SMoR's point, you've given examples of what wouldn't work but could you please give some examples of what input value and outputted rows you'd want to occur?

Comment: @J.D., the 3 bullets at the end of my question are good examples of expected output given certain filters. The input are the records in my second snippet.

Comment: @SMor, no, an `or` wouldn't work, because it *would* return record 1 in bullet #1 (where I explicitly mention I don't want record 1 to return in this case), and it *would* return record 3 in bullet #2 (again, I explicitly mention I don't want record 3 to return in this case).

Comment: Then the filter criteria is more complicated. And again - your logic is unclear. Given "2022-1-1" why do you ignore the first row? Beyond "this is what I want", you need to define a rule that can be implemented in code. Your last example contradicts your first example. Using filter 2025-1-1 you include row 4 based on d2 - how is that different from using filter 2022-1-1 and NOT including row 1? If rows 2 and 3 did not exist, would you then select row 1?

Comment: "*where I explicitly mention I don't want record 1 to return*" - You've not **explicitly** said that anywhere, which is why everyone here is telling you your post is unclear. I think I can derive what you're trying to say by taking a guess, which is you want to filter on `FirstDate`, for example `WHERE FirstDate = '2026-6-1'` and when that returns 0 rows then re-query the table filtering on `SecondDate = '2026-6-1'` which will return only the row with `Id` of 5, all in a single `WHERE` clause. If that's correct, then that's an example you should add to your post. Otherwise, I have no idea.

Comment: @J.D, your understanding is correct with regards for the expected result. Note, however, that you also suggest\assume an implementation ("requery the table" etc), which I don't know if it's the only way to do it - that's why I'm asking :) As for the explicitness, I was referring to the bold part in my #1 bullet point: *"records 2 & 3 will be returned (**but not 1!**)."* Not sure how to be more specific than the examples I gave in the bullet points; obviously, I can't demonstrate them with a `where` clause because, well, I'm asking how to construct it...

Comment: @SMor, *Given 2022-1-1 why do you ignore the first row* - We give "priority" to `FirstDate`, such that if there are any rows whose `FirstDate` value satisfies the filtered date, they are returned, and we don't look for `SecondDate` values. Rows 2 & 3 have `FirstDate` with `2022-1-1`, so we return them and stop; we don't look for rows with `SecondDate` with `2022-1-1`, hence row 1 is not returned. (2) *Using filter `2025-1-1` you include row 4 based on d2* - No row has `FirstDate` with the value of `2025-1-1`, so we continue to look for rows with `SecondDate` of `2025-1-1`, which is row 4.

Comment: Sorry for the misinterpretation of your original post, I think it's a little bit of a verbiage issue. "*records 2 & 3 will be returned (but not 1!).*" - sounds like you're saying you want record #1 returned but if you filter on both fields it's not returned and that's an issue. I understand you mean the opposite now. Also I didn't concretely mean to query the table twice when I said "*requery the table*", rather I was speaking loosely / abstractly. I understand you're asking for a *single query* type of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can essentially achieve your goal, with a single query, by leveraging a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and a [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like so:

```
DECLARE @SomeDate DATETIME = '2026-06-01';

WITH _Items AS
(
    SELECT 
        Id, 
        FirstDate, 
        SecondDate,
        MAX(CASE WHEN FirstDate = @SomeDate THEN 1 ELSE 0) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS IsMatchOnFirstDate
    FROM Items
)

SELECT
    Id,
    FirstDate,
    SecondDate
FROM _Items
WHERE (IsMatchOnFirstDate = 1 AND FirstDate = @SomeDate)
    OR (IsMatchOnFirstDate = 0 AND SecondDate = @SomeDate);
```

The way this basically works is the `IsMatchOnFirstDate` field is calculated by checking every row of the `Items` table for if the `FirstDate` field matches on the `@SomeDate` variable, and returning the value of 1 for **all** rows (hence window function) when there is a match on **any** of the rows.

The final select from the CTE then filters on the `FirstDate` only when `IsMatchOnFirstDate = 1` (meaning only when at least one of the rows from the `Items` table had a match on `FirstDate = @SomeDate`) otherwise it filters on `SecondDate` (since none of the rows matched by `FirstDate` when calculating `IsMatchOnFirstDate`).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a temp table
Run an insert select into the temp table and use @@rowcount to find out how many rows were inserted. Add an if statement and conditionally run the 2nd insert select.
Finally select the rows from the temp table to return the results